# How to repaint the UI inside DoDragDrop

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm implementing my app as a drag source. When I call DoDragDrop (Win32 call, not MFC) it enters into a modal loop and I don't get repaint messages in my main window until DoDragDrop returns. Unfortunately if I do a drop in the shell (a file) and the filename is already there the shell asks if I want to replace the file. But since me app is blocked because DoDragDrop  hasn't returned it isn't repainting and looks 'frozen'.

Any clues ?

Comment: This is a great question. I have an answer for .NET, but not Win32. :(

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a timer?  I ran into the same problem with `DoDragDrop()` and other blocking calls like `SHFileOperation()` and solved it using a call to `SetTimer()`.

EDIT: If you want more control over `DoDragDrop()` then a worker thread works well.  You can try calling `DoDragDrop()` in the worker thread, as someone suggested, but I couldn't get the mouse capture to work properly.  An easier solution is to call `DoDragDrop()` in the main thread and have the worker thread periodically post a `WM_USER` message to the main thread's queue.  `DoDragDrop()` will then retrieve the message and dispatch it to your window's `WndProc()`, at which time you can perform idle processing for as long as the queue remains empty.  If you give the worker thread a lower priority than the main thread, then it will execute and post the `WM_USER` message as soon as the main thread becomes idle (i.e., as soon as `DoDragDrop()` finishes processing all user input and calls MsgWaitForMultipleObjects() internally).  This method is better than the `SetTimer()` method because it gives your application full control over the CPU.  You don't have to wait up to 10ms (the minimum frequency that `SetTimer()` allows) after returning from your `WM_TIMER` handler returns before the next `WM_TIMER` message arrives.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest running the drag-and-drop operation on a different thread.  That way, DoDragDrop() will block the message loop in the new thread rather than the message loop in your UI thread.  If you take this approach, you should also consider (off the top of my head):

1. Any code that might be run from both your main thread and your drag-and-drop thread will need to be re-entrant.  As a corollary, you will need to protect any data structures used by both your main thread and your drag-and-drop thread.  If your application is already multi-threaded, you should be familiar with these concerns.
2. You should think about what happens if your user never responds to the shell's dialog box.  Can he continue to interact with your UI?  Can he invalidate the data that would have been 'dropped' in the pending operation?  Can he quit your application?

Comment: Matthew your answer makes no sense. I can't call DoDragDrop from a different thread. It's modal loop needs to be in the program main thread so it can get mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the real answer is to implement IAsyncOperation in my data object.